# How to customize (or disable) the automatic "back" button in JQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is is possible to customize (or simply disable) the automatic "back" button in JQueryMobile ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

To disable it just include `data-backbtn="false"` in the header div of your page.

Comment: thank you :) the docs are so hard to search through that I ended up finding the answer by reading the library code !

Answer (score 4):

To disable:

```
<div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false">
```

or

```
<div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true">
```

As far as customising goes, you can then create your own back button like this, which mimics the behavour of the original but lets you have more control over it:

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="c" data-role="button">Back</a>
```

> **The automatic toolbar back button is now off by default in jQuery mobile Beta 1.**