# how to disable back button in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize (or disable) the automatic “back” button in JQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478156/how-to-customize-or-disable-the-automatic-back-button-in-jquerymobile)

hi i am trying to develop a web page for mobile in which my requirement is

The user first goes from page A to page B then he cant go banck to page B by clicking on back button of browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code snippet,if you want to prevent going back to the previous page using browser back button

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

Actual source - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/11/disable-back-button-browser-javascript.html